# SSRS DataSourceCredentials and Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I have an application where I am rendering a SSRS report via the SOAP Web Service.  What I am attempting to do is to pass the credentials to the ReportExecutionService that will be used by the datasource for the database access.

This is currently working using SQL Authentication.  What I am trying to figure out is how to get this working for a user that is configured for the database using Windows Authentication. The user account is a domain user account, and I added this user to the database and to the db_owner role.

When I pass the credentials for a Windows User account and run SQL Profiler I get the following error message:

```
Login failed for user 'ourdomain\User'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

The following code is the (abbreviated) code that is working when passing the credentials for a SQL User, but failing with the above message when passing the domain user credentials:

```
public static byte[] RunReport(string reportPath, List<ReportParameter> reportParameters, ReportOutputType outputType)
        {
            ReportExecutionService reportExecutionService = new ReportExecutionService();

            var creds = new DataSourceCredentials[1];

            creds[0] = new DataSourceCredentials() { DataSourceName = "DynamicDataSource", UserName = ReportUserDomain + @"\" + ReportUserAccount, Password = ReportUserPassword };

            reportExecutionService.LoadReport(reportPath, null);

            reportExecutionService.SetExecutionCredentials(creds);

            return reportExecutionService.Render(Enum.GetName(typeof(ReportOutputType), outputType), GetDeviceInfo(outputType), out extension, out mimetype, out encoding, out warning, out streamids);
        }
```

Note that I added the ReportUserDomain parameter to the DataSourceCredentials to try to get this to work for Windows Auth, the code that is currently working for SQL Authentication does not include this variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was unable to figure out a way of passing Windows User Credentials via the `DataSourceCredentials` object and authenticate against SQL Server.  It seems that this functionality only supports SQL Server authentication.

What I ended up doing to solve the problem was to set the Data Source on all of the reports to "Use Windows Authentication (integrated security)" instead of "prompt for credentials".  I then pass the `DefaultCredentials` from the `CredentialCache` to the `ReportExecutionService`, which essentially passes the credentials for the Windows User that the AppPool is running under.  I then granted access to the database and SSRS for this Windows User Account, and things are working as expected.

This, unfortunately, does not account for the scenario of using the credentials for a Windows User account separate from the AppPool account. For instance, a user account that is used exclusively for reporting purposes.  Despite this, the solution is suitable for my needs.

Comment: Hi David, I have SSRS reporting server setup with user account that is used exclusively for reporting purposes. Now i am trying to run the ssrs through soap UI using "ReportExecutionService" class in C#. I am getting below error when i try to excute the code using SOAP UI call. Error Message "The permissions granted to user 'Domain\MachineName$' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'Domain\MachineName$' are insufficient for performing this operation"

Comment: hi niks - sounds like the account that is executing in your case is the Local Machine Account (`Domain\MachineName$`).  My assumption would be that you would need to update that to use a Domain User Account (see ["Using a Domain User Account as a Service Logon Account"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/domain-user-accounts) for some pointers), and not your Local Machine account, and that you would need to update permissions accordingly for this account in SQL Server / SSRS. I'm a little rusty here, but hopefully this helps point you in the right direction.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, David for a quick response. it helps me surely with my situation.

Comment: I found the reason was IIS App pool Identity setup as Network service so when my web service has been called externally it does not get enough permission to excute and render the report. I tried adding "Domainname\servername$" under secutirty for the report and database on SSRS but it still does not help. Do you have any suggestion or alternative solution? It works fine if I changed the App pool Identity to Domain\username .

Comment: I do not have an alternate solution, I think that `Domain\username` is probably the best practice (and using a dedicated service account) and possibly the only solution.